# Citing URL in latex

Tags: bibtex

**I've already asked this question on stackoverflow.com, but someone considered me to ask the question in this forum**

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902210/citing-in-url-in-latex

I am trying to write my bachelor's thesis in latex but I'm struggling with the URL in the literature. I use Citavi and converted it to a bib file. However, when inserting in latex, the URL citation doesn't look properly.

My prerequisites are: 
Windows 10 Pro Texmaker 5.0.2 Citavi 6.0.0.2

This is what my compiled file looks like:

> Literatur (2017): "Deforestation and Forest Degradation," .

That is what I'd need:

> International Union for Conservation of Nature (Hg.) (2017): Deforestation and Forest Degradation (Issues Brief). URL: https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf, zuletzt geprüft am 07.07.2018.

My Bib file, generated from Citavi, looks like this:

```
% This file was created with Citavi 6.0.0.2
@misc{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017,
editor = {{International Union for Conservation of Nature}},
year = {2017},
title = {Deforestation and Forest Degradation},
url = {\url   {https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-    forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf}},
urldate = {07.07.2018},
series = {Issues Brief}
}
```

and that is my current tex file. I've removed text and sections for clearity. But I've used all packages as in the original file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\sloppy

\begin{document}
\cite{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017}
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{Literatur1.2}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help - I'am a totally newbee and therefore thankful for every advice. Even if it's a different approach to citing properly. 
Magdalena

Comment: Aside: You may be able to inform Citavi that you use BibTeX and `natbib` with a fairly old bibliography style, and hence that bib entries shouldn't use the `url` and `urldate` field names. Ideally, Citavi would place the URL string in a field called `note`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ecta` (Econometrica, right?) bibliography style doesn't recognize fields named `url`, `urldate`, and `series` for entries of type `@misc`. Moreover, for entries of type `@misc`, it doesn't process `editor` fields either. You need to change the name of the `url` field to `note`, and you need to change the `editor` field name to `author`. If you want the information contained in the `urldate` field to be shown in the formatted bib entry as well, be sure to make it part of the `note` field. And, copy the information in the `series` field ("Issues Brief") to the end of the `author` field.

For the `\url` macro to work, you must load either the `url` package and/or the `hyperref` package. If you want the citation call-outs and any URL strings in the bibliography to be made into hyperlinks, you should definitely load the `hyperref` package.

Two additional comments. First, the `german` and `ngerman` packages are obsolete. *Don't load them.* Instead, load the `babel` package with the option `german` or `ngerman`; use the latter option if your document is supposed to adhere to post-1997 (1998?) spelling and hyphenation conventions. Second, don't manipulate the low-level `\baselinestretch` parameter directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue a suitable `\setstretch` directive.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % just to make this answer self-contained
\begin{filecontents}{Literatur12.bib}
@misc{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017,
  author = {{International Union for Conservation of Nature}},
  year   = {2017},
  title  = {Deforestation and Forest Degradation (Issues Brief)},
  note   = {\url{https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf}, 
            zuletzt geprüft am 07.07.2018},
  urldate = {07.07.2018},
  series = {Issues Brief}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=3cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}

%%\usepackage{german} % 'german' package is obsolete
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % don't modify this low-level parameter directly
\usepackage{setspace} % instead, use the 'setspace' package
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % 'hyphens' option allows line breaks after "-" characters
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017}
%\section{Literaturverzeichnis} % not necessary
\bibliography{Literatur12}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your very helpful response and your further advice! this works very well!

Comment: I am wondering can you help me in this topic please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661304/absence-of-arxivs-link-in-the-references?noredirect=1#comment1645327_661304

Comment: @zfr - Is my impression correct that your main objective, now that you've found a bibliography style (`plainurl`) that doesn't ignore `url` fields, is to place the publication year after rather than before the URL string? If it's not that, is it a desire to abbreviate first names? Something else still? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem is modifying your bibliography template (ecta). There is the package named [urlbst](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst) containing Perl script doing some tricky things.

The package adds new entry type (webpage) and recognizes new fields: url and lastchecked (instead of urldate). On the other hand there will be needed sam minor changes to generated BibTeX template to meet your needs.

After some minor changes to your files:
bibliography file:

```
@webpage{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017,
  Title                    = {Deforestation and Forest Degradation},
  Editor                   = {International Union for Conservation of Nature},
  LastChecked              = {07.07.2018},
  Series                   = {Issues Brief},
  Url                      = {https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf},
  Year                     = {2017}
}
```

and LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl}             %%% <----------- ADDED
\usepackage{hyperref}         %%% <----------- ADDED
\bibliographystyle{ecta_url}  %%% <----------- CHANGED
\sloppy

\begin{document}
\cite{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017}
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

And the BibTeX template: [ecta-url](https://pastebin.com/g2B2dRf8) (created by [urlbst](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst)).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I've already solved the problem and therefore did not try this one out - but I may do so in further files

Comment: The contents of the `editor` field (a "corporate" author) must be enclosed in a double pair of curly braces. Otherwise -- as is shown in your screenshot -- BibTeX parses the name quite incorrectly: Given-name components `International` and `Union`, "von" component `for`, and surname component `Conservation of Nature`. Yikes! Do write `editor = {{International Union for Conservation of Nature}}` to avoid this problem. A separate issue: Are you sure that `@webpage` is the correct entry type for the document at hand? The document is a pdf file, *not* an html file or other type of webpage.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is manually format the bibliography using `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` and `\end{thebibliography}`.

Additionally, I suspect you want to customize the citation style, an example is available at https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Natbib_citation_styles

The best situation would be read the natbib documentation.

Comment: The OP's issues are related mainly to the formatting of a bibliographic entry. The `natbib` package does *not* affect these formatting matters directly. Hence, suggesting to the OP that he/she read the `natbib` documentation is probably not all that helpful.

Comment: darn, I'm new hmm.