# Absence of arxiv's link in the references

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I am writing my research statement and I have the following issue: I need to cite an article from ArXiv so that in the references there is a arxiv's link to that paper.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
%\documentclass[16pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% change title size
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\normalsize}{\Large}{}{}
% change author size
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\MakeUppercase {\authors }}{\MakeUppercase{\large\authors}}{}{}
% change section title size
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\large}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\title{\textbf{Research Statement}}
\author{Agent Smith}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\large

In \cite{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.2209.04932}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refref.bib}
  
\end{document}
```

If you compile this code you will see the following and there is no arxiv link in the references.
[image]

The content of refref.bib file is the below which I exported from arxiv.
I am not so advanced user of Overleaf but can anyone explain to me how to fix that issue?
I've tried to search for the similar questionand tried something but it did not help.

Many thanks!

```
@misc{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.2209.04932,
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.2209.04932},
  
  url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.04932},
  
  author = {Gowers, W. T. and Karam, Thomas},
  
  keywords = {Combinatorics (math.CO), Number Theory (math.NT), FOS: Mathematics, FOS: Mathematics, 11T06 (Primary) 11B30, 15A69 (Secondary)},
  
  title = {Equidistribution of high-rank polynomials with variables restricted to subsets of $\mathbb{F}_p$},
  
  publisher = {arXiv},
  
  year = {2022},
  
  copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International}
}
```

**EDIT:** I've followed the advice of @DavidCarlisle but this is what I have. [image]

I really would like to have like the below picture:
[image]

Comment: Whether an element is included in a bib entry is determined by the `.bst` file used (you are using `plain`).  Check to see if there is a `\url` element in the `.bbl` file for this entry.  If not, you need to use a `.bst` file that includes it.  Since you\ are using the `amsart` class, you might try `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}`; I think that includes a url.

Comment: Off topic: Since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, no need to explicitly load the latter.  Similarly with `mathtools` and `amsmath`; also, `amsthm` is built into `amsart`.  And `hyperref` should be loaded last with a few exceptions specified in the documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, sorry but I did not understand most portion of your comment. I do not have `.bst` and `.bbl` files. Can you give a full detailed answer which solves my problem?

Comment: The presence of `\bibliographystyle{plain}` indicates that bibtex is being used to process the bibliography.  That will call on a "library" file `plain.bst` to convert the `.bib` file to a form digestible by LaTeX.  The Overleaf procedure does this automatically, producing a `.bbl` file which is read in by a second LaTeX run on your `.tex` file.  I don't use Overleaf, so I can't tell you where to look for the `.bbl` file, but it should be mentioned in your log.  If you need help finding these, perhaps best to ask Overleaf support.j

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}` is considerably older than the web, so has nothing about URLs. Use a bibliography style that does have a `url` field

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry but what does it mean? I am so confused

Comment: change `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to (for example) `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I changed it but does not look as I want. Please see the edit!

Comment: don't edit the answer into the question. There are thousands of bibtex styles the one  suggested answers the question but there are of course others. The box you show is hyperref link box you can use hyperref options to not use that and just color the link.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry I really did not get what you are talking about. Can you give some concrete answer?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}` is a concrete answer to the question you asked originally.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, but this is not what I meant. I edited my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can you help me please?

Comment: Your objecctives for the formatted bibliographic entries aren't clear. Is it the placement of the `year` at the very end? Is it the abbreviation of given names? Is it the fact that surnames are placed before rather than after the abbreviated given names? Is it the use of smallcaps for the rendering of the surname? Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico, thanks a lot for your attention! 1) I want to place a year after url link. 2) I would like to have just a link to arxiv. In my case you see "URL: link". I mean I do not want this "URL:" 3) I would like to make sizefond ont he references a bit larger. Hope it is clear! I'll highly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Mico, I am wondering have you seen my last comment?

Comment: You have issued quite a few demand, yet have left a lot of crucial conditions unspecified. All I can suggest is that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package. Then, run the `makebst` utility and answer the multiple choice questions. Based on your answers, the `makebst` utility will craeate a bespoke bibliography style (bst) file that satisfies all of your bibliography-related formatting requirements.

Comment: @Mico, I think that I specified my question very well but for some reason you did not give an answe. Thank you!